# Huge time difference on creating numpy.zeros for tiny difference in size of array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was trying to determine the time complexity of doing `numpy.zeros` so I ran the following tests.  It seems to be linear with the size of the array you're creating, but at a certain point there is a huge disparity on how much time it takes.  Here are the interesting cases where **hardly changing the array size at all changes the creation time by an order of magnitude**.

```
python -m timeit -n 1000 -s "import numpy" "numpy.zeros(64500, dtype=float)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 33.5 usec per loop


python -m timeit -s "import numpy" "numpy.zeros(65000, dtype=float)"
1000 loops, best of 3: 418 usec per loop
```

That is a *huge disparity*!  Below an array of size 64500 the time complexity is roughly linear with array size, and **above** an array of size 65000 the time complexity is roughly linear.  **Why is there such a staggering time difference here?**

My understanding is that internally Python stores everything in its own special heap.  Is this occurring because numpy uses C, and it stores arrays of a certain size on the C stack and arrays of another size on the C heap?  I'm not even sure if that question makes sense.

I'm using 32-bit python 3.3.1 and numpy 1.7.0rc1 on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: On my machine (Ubuntu 64 bit, etc) timings are almost the same (~23 usec)

Comment: Forget about the C stack, numpy objects can't use it. The space would be freed before the object is even returned to Python.

Comment: @MrE I've tested it on three Win7 computers (2 at work and 1 at home) and it's _around_ the same for each.  Maybe there's a different cutoff on your computer?  Or maybe not one at all?

Comment: @delnan good to know; now I have **no** idea what's going on though.

Comment: On a 64 bit Ubuntu installation, I get a jump (but much less drastic) near `zeros(2**17, float)`.  Perhaps this is a cache effect?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser weird that it's about one power of two greater than where I'm experiencing it... what does that mean?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I downloaded and installed Python 64-bit and numpy for Windows, and I'm getting the same thing you are around `2**17`.  I still don't know _why_ though.

Answer (score 1):

[image: The x axis is log(i), the y axis is the time/i]

I had the same problem on my computer. Don't know to explain it.

I plotted the time divided by the length of the array, so it is supposed to stay constant if the time complexity is linear.

the plot is average of 10 runs, so the high peak is keep seeming in every trial

(The numbers on the x axis are log of the array size, while the y is time in second divided by the array size)

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code on my computer. it is almost the same time for the per loop in two different experiment, this is not for the stack /heap problem, because the memory location will in the same may, I think it maybe the memory problem. the memory of my computer is 16GB.

Comment: Are you using 64 bit python?

Comment: The 64-bit jump seems to happen around 130000 elements, and is not as dramatic.